# Flash Clipboard Questions

Tags: flash, permissions, bitmap, clipboard

I'd like to create a site similar to imgur.com that allows easy screenshot uploading. Because I don't know much about Flash yet, I'd like to know if the following is possible.

1. Can I read bitmap clipboard data with a Flash applet embedded into a web page with the standard security profile?
2. If 1. is possible, am I likely to run into any roadblocks when I try to transform this clipboard data into an image file (preferably PNG) and upload it through HTTP?

I found the following page, and it reads "AIR only". Does that mean that this class can only be used in desktop applications developed in Flash? Are there any other ways?

[livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html)

Thanks!

Comment: Can imgur read my clipboard and upload screenshots without needing me to save it and point to the file from an upload control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No
2. see above :)

and yes, if the docs say 'AIR only' it can only be used in desktop apps.